# Any idea to group tag route with the other routes above while not breaking the route below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We have a requirement to have a following URL structure
`site.com/tag-name`

Our current route is below.

```
get '/posts/:something' => 'mypage#post'

get '/whatever' => 'mypage#whatever'
get '/about' => 'mypage#about'

get '/:tag', to: 'mypost#tag'
```

Is there anyway to move the `/:tag` route above to group with the other route above without breaking the route below ?
For example, if I move `/:tag` route above, the `/whatever` and `/about` will not work.

```
get '/posts/:something' => 'mypage#post'
get '/:tag', to: 'mypost#tag'

get '/whatever' => 'mypage#whatever'
get '/about' => 'mypage#about'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [advanced constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints), warning: looks ugly

Like this:

```
# routes
get '/posts/:something' => 'mypage#post'
get ':tag', to: 'mypost#tag',
    constraints: lambda { |request| not ["whatever", "about"].include?(request.params[:tag]) }

get '/whatever' => 'mypage#whatever'
get '/about' => 'mypage#about'
```